# How can I get the corresponding value of a column based on an aggregate of another column?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, maxby

I am migrating some PostgreSQL queries to Snowflake and I am struggling to replicate the following query:

```
WITH test_table(col1, col2, col3, col4) AS (
    VALUES 
        (1, 1, 7, 5),
        (1, 1, 6, 4),
        (1, 2, 1, 4),
        (1, 2, 2, 5),
        (1, 2, 3, 6)
)

SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    (max(ARRAY[col3, col4]))[2]
FROM test_table
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

This query manages to get the value of `col4` that corresponds to the maximum value of `col3 grouped by col1, col2`. However, I do not find any elegant solution to replicate this on Snowflake.

Comment: Please add some example source data to allow everyone to easily replicate your results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can aggregate an array by any order. So you can group `col3` ordered by `col4`:

```sql
with test_table(col1, col2, col3, col4) 
as (
    select * from (values 
        (1, 1, 20, 1), -- added 
        (1, 1, 7, 5),
        (1, 1, 6, 4),
        (1, 2, 1, 4),
        (1, 2, 2, 5),
        (1, 2, 3, 6))
)

SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    array_agg(col4) within group(order by col3 desc) c4_by_max_c3
FROM test_table
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

[image]

Instead of getting this array, you can just pick the top number with `[0]`:

```sql
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    array_agg(col4) within group(order by col3 desc)[0] c4_by_max_c3
FROM test_table
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

[image]

Hopefully Snowflake will also support `max_by` in the future, but it's not yet implemented. Meanwhile this will work.

---

### 2023 Update: MAX_BY() is supported

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min_by.html

Comment: MAX_BY is now supported in Snowflake

Comment: Good call! https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min_by.html